# How to display MySQL results when no matches found in tables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote the following query function to be accessed by a form where the user selects a skill from a drop down list and must enter a city. The results are correctly displayed when there is a match of skill and city. Here's the code:

```
function search() {
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    if(!isset($_POST['city'])) echo "You must enter a city to find a match.";

    $sql = "SELECT skill.skill_name, team.city FROM skill INNER JOIN team ON skill.skill_id=team.skill WHERE skill.skill_name LIKE '$skill' AND city LIKE '$city' ";
    foreach ($myconnect->query($sql) as $row) {
      if($sql) {
          echo $skill . " is available in " . $row['city'];
      }
      else {
         if(!$sql)
            echo "No result found.";
         }
      }
  }//submit
}
```

To clarify: When a match is found the code correctly displays the message. But when there is no match it does not display the message that no result was found.

Comment: what is the actual problem? I dont understand the title: is that what you want, or what is happening now!?

Comment: `if($sql)`? Getting zero rows from MySQL will not remove the SQL code from your PHP variable.

Comment: What this condition is supposed to check, `if($sql)`?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, thanks for your input. I've just replaced my script with yours and now I get "No results found" for all queries, whether there's a match. Could you please explain what's going on? I'm not familiar with the syntax and the s and t etc so I don't know how to go about making adjustments.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, I'm assuming on closer observation that these are declarations: "skill s" and  "team t"?

Comment: where $skill variable is supposed to come from

Comment: @Your Common Sense, after hours of pouring over PHP/MySql documentation on php.net and w3schools about prepared statements and bind param, it was two simple things that were causing perpetual no result: I should have changed your $_POST['skill'] to $_POST['skills'] and, I don';t know why but PHP says there were no indexes for $row['skill_name'] and $row['city'] so using the form vars $_POST['skills']  and $_POST['city'] has killed that error.

Thanks for the answer and for making me aware of prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are too many wrong answers around, so it worth to write a proper one.

```
$sql = "SELECT s.skill_name, t.city FROM skill s JOIN team t ON s.skill_id=t.skill 
        WHERE s.skill_name = ? AND city = ?";
$stmt = $myconnect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['skill'], $_POST['city']);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
if (!$data) {
    echo "No result found.";
} else {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['skill_name']) . " is available in " . htmlspecialchars($row['city']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Flawless. I've removed my answer just to make yours more visible :)